# Reference Request: Spectral Sequence Relating Bredon and Borel Equivariant Cohomology.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

Given a compact Lie group $G$ and a $G$-space $X$, useful invariants may obtained by studying the equivariant cohomology of $X$. There are various equivariant cohomology theories that may be defined, and in general return different information about $X$ and its $G$-action. My question is to how a certain pair of these theories may be related. Specifically:

> Let $X$ be a $G$ space for $G$ a compact Lie group. Is there a spectral sequence relating the Borel cohomology $H^*_G(X)$ and the Bredon cohomology $\mathcal{H}^*_G(X)$ of $X$?

Comment: In the book *Equivariant homotopy and cohomology theory* of May, Chapter IV, Section 2, it is stated (if I understand correctly) that given an abelian group $A$, and $\underline{A}$ the corresponding constant sheaf, you have $H^*_G(X;A) = \mathcal{H}^*_G(EG \times X; \underline{A})$.

Comment: I believe that the result in the book is stated for $G$ a finite $p$-group, but the statements do hold for compact Lie groups, too. The constant coefficients are a little restrictive for what I need, however.